# Using Map with If

Tags: map

I have an If statement I need to carry out where the result should be a single number for each time the if is executed. What I have at the moment returns a list for each time the If is executed. I specifically do not want to use a Do loop so is there a way to use Map to do this?

```
x = {0.897409001634915`, 0.897409001634915`, 0.897409001634915`, 
   0.897409001634915`, 0.897409001634915`, 0.897409001634915`, 
   0.897409001634915`, 0.897409001634915`, 0.897409001634915`, 
   0.897409001634915`, 0.897409001634915`, 0.897409001634915`, 
   0.897409001634915`, 0.897409001634915`, 0.897409001634915`, 
   0.897409001634915`, 0.897409001634915`, 0.897409001634915`, 
   0.897409001634915`, 0.897409001634915`};
y = {0.897409001634915`, 0.897409001634915`, 0.897409001634915`, 
   0.897409001634915`, 0.897409001634915`, 0.897409001634915`, 
   0.897409001634915`, 0.897409001634915`, 0.897409001634915`, 
   0.897409001634915`, 0.897409001634915`, 0.897409001634915`, 
   0.897409001634915`, 0.897409001634915`, 0.897409001634915`, 
   0.897409001634915`, 0.897409001634915`, 0.897409001634915`, 
   0.897409001634915`, 0.897409001634915`};
z = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

TimeModelSelection[41]
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

The first few lines of the result are

```
Map[If[# == 0, x*y, z] &, TimeModelSelection[41], {1}]
{{0.8053429162, 0.8053429162, 0.8053429162, 0.8053429162, 
  0.8053429162, 0.8053429162, 0.8053429162, 0.8053429162, 
  0.8053429162, 0.8053429162, 0.8053429162, 0.8053429162, 
  0.8053429162, 0.8053429162, 0.8053429162, 0.8053429162, 
  0.8053429162, 0.8053429162, 0.8053429162, 
  0.8053429162}, {0.8053429162, 0.8053429162, 0.8053429162, 
  0.8053429162, 0.8053429162, 0.8053429162, 0.8053429162, 
  0.8053429162, 0.8053429162, 0.8053429162, 0.8053429162, 
  0.8053429162, 0.8053429162, 0.8053429162, 0.8053429162, 
  0.8053429162, 0.8053429162, 0.8053429162, 0.8053429162, 
  0.8053429162},...
```

I have also tried thefollowing without luck

```
Map[If[# == 0, x[[#]]*y[[#]], z[[#]]] &, TimeModelSelection[41], {1}]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand the statement, you wish to do this:

```
Table[If[time[[i]] == 0, x[[i]] y[[i]], z[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[time]}]
```

but you wish to do it without `Table` or `Do`. One way to accomplish this is quite straightforward:

```
(1 - time) x y + time z
```

which gives the same result as above, though this assumes that the `time` variable is either zero (when you wish to have x*y) or one (when you wish to use z). This uses `time` as shorthand for your variable `TimeModelSelection[41]`.

Another, more "functional programming" way to approach this is to define the basic operation as a function:

```
f[{t_, x_, y_, z_}] := If[t == 0, x y, z]
```

and then call the function using `Map`

```
Map[f, # &, {1}] /@ Transpose[{time, x, y, z}]
```

which again gives the same answer. Finally, for the purists, you can do the same thing without defining any auxiliary function (like `f`) by using pure functions

```
Apply[If, {#[[1]] == 0, #[[2]] #[[3]], #[[4]]} &, {1}] /@ Transpose[{time, x, y, z}]
```

though it is probably hard to read. Mr. Wizard's use of `MapThread` is probably a better and more readable way to get a purely functional form than this use of `Apply`.

Comment: The (1-time)xy... answer is great. It's exactly what I needed, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

[bill](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1783/bill-s) already showed how to do this very efficiently with a numeric approach, but a bit closer to what you attempted and your direct request is `MapThread`:

```
SeedRandom[1]
time = RandomInteger[1, 20]

MapThread[If[# == 0, #2*#3, #4] &, {time, x, y, z}]
```

> ```
> {0, 0, 0.805343, 0, 0.805343, 0.805343, 0.805343, 0, 0.805343, 1, 0.805343, 0.805343,
>  0.805343, 0.805343, 0.805343, 0.805343, 0.805343, 0, 0, 0}
> ```

Comment: If the OP wants named variables instead of slots, then this can be done: `MapThread[Function[{t, x, y, z}, If[t == 0, x y, z]], {time, x, y, z}]`.